# How to get the other side of the Relationship

Tags: ios, objective-c, parse-platform

I am using parse as a DB for my app.
I am creating in the app a on to many relationship between two objects. taken from the Parse docs

```
// Create the post
PFObject *myPost = [PFObject objectWithClassName:@"Post"];
myPost[@"title"] = @"I'm Hungry";
myPost[@"content"] = @"Where should we go for lunch?";

// Create the comment
PFObject *myComment = [PFObject objectWithClassName:@"Comment"];
myComment[@"content"] = @"Let's do Sushirrito.";

// Add a relation between the Post and Comment
myComment[@"parent"] = myPost;

// This will save both myPost and myComment
[myComment saveInBackground];
```

After saving the relationship how would i get the myComment object from the myPost object?
Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not a two-way relation. You won't get the myComment object from the myPost object. You'll get the myComment object from querying the Comments class for comments whose "parent" is set to myPost.

```
PFQuery *query = [PFQuery queryWithClassName:@"Comment"];
[query whereKey:@"parent" equalTo:myPost];
[query findObjectsInBackgroundWithBlock:^(NSArray *objects, NSError *error) {
    ...
}];
```